# How to calculate probability of a random sampling of a population

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling

Let's say that I have a city for which I know the size in square miles and I want to know the probability of a random sample of individuals from that population living within a certain threshold of miles from each other. So, for example, say I have a city that is 14 square miles and I randomly sample 3 individuals from this population; what is the probability that those 3 individuals live within 6 miles of each other?

The questions I have regarding this problem are:
1. How can I go about setting up this problem?
2. Is it fairly straight forward, or do I have to account for things like the layout of the city, urban vs rural, more downtown space (think Chicago or New York City) vs more suburban space, etc?
3. Do I need more information such as population density?
    - UPDATE: Let's assume the population density is approximately 7,000 people per square mile.

I apologize if the question isn't formatted in the typical CV format; if needs some improvements, please let me know and I'll fix the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you wish to randomly sample individuals from a population and then estimate the density of residence throughout the city grid?

Comment: @AdamO I'm saying that I currently have a random draw of 3 individuals and know that they live within 6 miles of each other. I'd like to be able to say whether that is statistically significant or is simply within the bounds of what one would expect from a random draw. That's why I think I need to take into account other factors like population density, but I don't know how to incorporate that.

Comment: Working in demography, you would need some knowledge of how the population is distributed. The only working assumption might be a uniform distribution of the population over the grid. That would be ludicrous. We know cities are very heterogenously dense. So I wouldn't really be bothered by the problem.

Comment: If you ever find the population density distribution up to by a constant, you could maybe use Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods to compute that? Like throw 3 random centers sampled by the density, trace circles of radius 6 miles, check %overlap <= 95 say, depending on alpha. Then you can repeat.

Comment: @AdamO Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by you wouldn't be bothered by the problem, please? Do you mean that 6 miles of each other doesn't seem like that much? Or do you mean that there's not much that can be done with the current information available?

Comment: Essentially try searching for a population density grid with a small enought resolution (http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/grump-v1-population-density/data-download)

Comment: @brittenb This is a heatmap of the population density of New York: http://cdn.beergraphs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/content/New_York_Population_Map.png are you saying you do or do not have such information on the region which you're sampling from? (or is this a "thought experiment")?

Comment: @AdamO No, I don't have that information; I've tried to find it online with no current success. It seems like that's the information I'd need though. Once I had that, I could just use some statistical software to randomly plot three points within those boundaries, weighted by the densities, and find the distance between them, right?

Comment: @brittenb Yes! Very much so! It would be difficult to solve mathematically, but very easy with software. MCMC using the metropolis hastings algorithm would make short work of it.

Comment: @AdamO I'm getting very close to being able to solve my problem, but am stuck on a current step. I've downloaded the necessary census data to generate a map similar to the one you showed of New York. What I'd like to do now is randomly sample 3 tracts, where the probability of sampling a specific tract is weighted by the population density. Is there a demographically sound way of doing this? I don't understand MCMC metropolist hastings at all :-/